# how to user parametrized method in TimerCallback C#

Tags: c#, timer, delegates

I'm Trying To create Multiple Timers to run at the same time, So I created List.
I want all the timers to run the same function but with different parameters.

```
private void reporting()
        {
            try
            {
               for (int i = 0; i < timers.Count; i++)
                {
                    timers[i] = new Timer(new TimerCallback(Task(i)));
                    //Set the Default Time.
                    DateTime scheduledTime = DateTime.MinValue;


                        //Set the Scheduled Time by adding the Interval to Current Time.

                        scheduledTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2);
                        if (DateTime.Now > scheduledTime)
                        {
                            //If Scheduled Time is passed set Schedule for the next Interval.
                            scheduledTime = scheduledTime.AddMinutes(2);
              
                    TimeSpan TimeSpan = scheduledTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);

                    int dueTime = Convert.ToInt32(TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds);

                    //Change the Timer's Due Time.
                    timers[i].Change(dueTime, Timeout.Infinite);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
            }
        }
```

here is the method I want to call

```
 private void Task(int index)
        {
            this.WriteToFile("*************"+ScheduleReport[index].Name+" Started*****************");

            this.WriteToFile("*************"+ScheduleReport[index].Name+" Finished successfully {0}*****************");
        }
```

and this code gives me an error in this line

```
timers[i] = new Timer(new TimerCallback(Task(i)));
```

method name Expected

Comment: `new TimerCallback(_ => Task(i))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`TimerCallback`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timercallback) expects a function that accepts one parameter of type `object` and returns `void`.

You are currently *invoking* the `Task(int)` method, effectively trying to pass `void` to `TimerCallback`, which clearly is not valid.

You need to wrap the invocation of `Task(int)` in another function, who's signature complies with the `TimerCallback` delegate i.e. create a closure.

One way way to achieve this would be via a local function:

```
void InvokeTaskWithIndex(object _) => Task(i);
timers[i] = new Timer(new TimerCallback(InvokeTaskWithIndex));
```

But a lambda expression would be more concise:

```
timers[i] = new Timer(new TimerCallback(_ => Task(i)));
```

And you don't even need to manually construct a `TimerCallback` instance, because lambda expressions are implicitly convertible to delegates:

```
timers[i] = new Timer(_ => Task(i));
```